# combining multiple || in do while

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

I'm making a simple rock papper scissors game in JS;

I did it according to my task, but I wanted to improove it. I want to forbid user from putting anything but "rock" "papper" or "scissors" into the prompt window. Without minding weather it's upper case or lower case.

Everything works properly except for filtering out all the unwanted words.

I'm quite sure that the problem lays within the while line. If I delete everything and leave just, say, papper, it works a.k.a. it doesn't accept anything until I write papper, but if I want to do this with all of these, it doesn't allow me to enter anything. It keeps on refreshing.

Any Ideas? :)

```js
alert("Lets play rock, papper scissors!");
//******COMPUTER'S PICK
var cPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
switch(cPick){
 case 1:
 cPick = "rock";
 break;
 case 2:
 cPick = "papper";
 break;
 case 3:
 cPick = "scissors";
 break;
}
console.log(cPick);
//******YOUR PICK
var isValid = false;
//*********
var yourPick; 
do{ 
 yourPick = prompt("Your pick! Choose Rock, Papper of Scissors");
 yourPick = yourPick.toLowerCase();
 console.log(yourPick);
} while ((yourPick !=="papper") || (yourPick!=="rock") || (yourPick!=="scissors"));
 if (yourPick == cPick){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You both chose " + yourPick + "! It's a tie.");
  } else if (yourPick == "rock" && cPick == "scissors"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You've picked " + yourPick + ". Computer choose " + cPick + "! You win!");
  } else if (yourPick == "scissors" && cPick == "papper"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You've picked " + yourPick + ". Computer choose " + cPick + "! You win!");
  } else if (yourPick == "papper" && cPick == "rock"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You've picked " + yourPick + ". Computer choose " + cPick + "! You win!");
  } else if (yourPick == "rock" && cPick == "papper"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You've picked " + yourPick + ". Computer choose " + cPick + "! You loose!");
  } else if (yourPick == "scissors" && cPick == "rock"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You've picked " + yourPick + ". Computer choose " + cPick + "! You loose!");
  } else if (yourPick == "papper" && cPick == "scissors"){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You've picked " + yourPick + ". Computer choose " + cPick + "! You loose!");
  }
```

```css
.container{
 width: 80%;
 background-color: cyan;
 border: 4px solid blue;
 color: black;
 margin: 20rem auto;
 text-align: center;
}
#demo{
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <p id="demo"></p>
 </div>

 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `&&` to combine the (negative) conditions, not `||` because your

```
(x != A) || (x != B) || (x != C)
```

is the same as:

```
!(x == A) || !(x == B) || !(x == C)
```

which is the same as:

```
!(x == A && x == B && x == C)
```

Where the final step is from [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Since your string cannot possibly be equal to A, B and C all at the same time, the expression is always `!false` (i.e. `true`) and the `while` loop never terminates.

Comment: It's nice that you have added De Morgan's law, but you're missing a step there (just to be more understandable) `!(x == A && x == B && x == C)  -> !(x == A) || !(x == B) || !(x == C)` and `!(a == b) -> a != b`

Comment: @KarelG oh, that bit - I took the `!(a == b) -> a != b` as self evident :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`, because you want to prompt the user while it is different than rock AND paper AND scissors

Answer (score 0):

This condition will **always** be true, and thus you can never break out of the while loop.

```
(yourPick !=="papper") || (yourPick!=="rock") || (yourPick!=="scissors")
```

Because you are using logical OR, only one part of the expression must be true for the entire thing to be true.  And even if the user enters "papper", for example, it is still true that "papper" does not equal "rock".  So the expression evaluates to true overall.

You need `&&` instead:

```
(yourPick !=="papper") && (yourPick!=="rock") && (yourPick!=="scissors")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ((yourPick !=="papper") && (yourPick!=="rock") && (yourPick!=="scissors"));
```

use `&&` instead of `||` ;-)